# Bash - Get specific argument using number in variable

Tags: bash, variables, terminal, arguments

I want to access an argument from when the script was run, and I want to get the specific argument based on the variable. So I want to get the argument `$2` but rather than typing two, I use the variable that contains a number

Something like this

`FOO=2
echo $FOO`

The problem is both variables and arguments both use `$` so I don't know how to call an specific argument based on the number in the variable. I know I'm explaining this terribly, correct me if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash allows indirection with the `${!name}` notation, where `name` is the name of a variable whose value is the name of the variable you want to access.  So, in your example you could print the second positional parameter like

```
foo=2
printf '%s\n' "${!foo}"
```

or

```
printf 'The value at %s is %s\n' "$foo" "${!foo}"
```

which will print something like

```
The value at 2 is secondParameterValue
```

Some good reading on indirection can be found [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)